# Can't access website hosted on my computer from LAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, webserver

I am trying to access my webserver from another computer and from mobile over local network using IP of host server.

I figured out that its not the problem of sever specific as I already tried different sever.
Problem is only with some setting of windows which I am missing out.

I added inbound rule to access my localhost over LAN but no luck.

What I did for resolve:

1. Disabled firewall
2. Tried tomcat sever and wampserver both
3. Checked using Advance port scanner but it saying port is not open.
   Even server is not accessible on same computer using IP.

OS: Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Please improve the question; it is not clear what you've tried or what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to access a webserver running on your computer from another computer in your LAN? Are you trying to access http: //localhost on the other computer?

Answer (score -1):

Can you access the website in the computer it is hosted at?

- **Yes**

Issue `ipconfig` to see what's your router's address (it'l be displayed as default gateway), access that from a web browser and open/trigger port 80 for TCP/UDP, or whatever other port is being used by the server. `ipconfig`to see the local address of the server (usually 198.162.1.X), connect to that from any other computer on the LAN and you should be able to browse your website.

- **No**

Probably a server configuration problem. Ask at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) providing more details like what server you're running and post your configuration files. It's hard to help with only the few details you gave.

Comment: I can able to ping to my host computer and also able access shared files using IP/host-name. So I guess there is no problem with address.

Even if am trying to access my webserver from host computer using IP:8080, it's not responding only localhost is working.

Comment: Use `localhost` from the local host and the internal IP from other computers in the LAN...

Comment: Ok.. finally I found the problem. It's my Antivirus ESET.
I needed to configure ports and LAN in trusted zone. But ESET is behaving weird, earlier I disabled all protection including firewall of ESET. it was still blocking the traffic. 
Thanks for help.